# main.xml file is not reachable/accessible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I downlaoded an example from the Internet to learn more about the AugmentedReality.

And when I tried to import the project, eclipse couldnt find any project and then, i decided

to copy all the files one by one in a new project I created. But, when I tried to fix some

error, I could not fix and error reads: "main canot be resolved or is not a field"

this error appeared around 'setContentView(R.layout.main);' despite of, in the resources file

there is a main.xml file, but eclipse cant find it.

any suggestions to fix such an error?

**LOGCAT**:

```
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imrannazar.sobel/com.imrannazar.sobel.Sobel}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.imrannazar.sobel.OverlayView
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.imrannazar.sobel.OverlayView
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at com.imrannazar.sobel.Sobel.onCreate(Sobel.java:74)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    ... 11 more
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
05-17 16:56:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12497):    ... 21 more

Comment: Have you cleaned this project?

Comment: what do u mean by "cleaned"? though, i dont think so

Comment: Select "Project -> Clean" in eclipse

Comment: Try to import the project using the "New Android Project" tool and select : Create project from existing source and then browse to where your project folder is .

Comment: i have just done it now, but what does it do? because the error remains

Comment: did you try creating a new project from existing source?

Comment: Can you provide code of the java file where you are using **setContentView(R.layout.main)**

Comment: now, when I created new project from an existing one, no errors. but the app just crashs

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Comment: Also, you should stick to one issue per question.  Your issue with main.xml has been resolved, so you should accept an answer.  If you are having a new issue, post a new question.  This keeps things from getting muddled and running on forever in a single question.

Comment: ok, thanks for telling me...and sorry for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have an import like:

```
import android.R;
```

Remove it and your problem should be gone.

Comment: @psychicLit it is useful to post LogCat messages when you're asking for help with crashes

Comment: import android.R exists, but deleteing it, highlight R in R.layout.main, and when mouse over R, eclipse suggests ti import android.R

Comment: add `import your_package_name.R;`

Comment: Did you tried importing R with your correct package name and cleaning the project then? What happens after doing it?

Comment: there is something in main.xml like this:<com.imrannazar.sobel.OverlayView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/surface_overlay" />

Answer (score 3):

Look for

```
import android.R
```

Delete it, then clean your project and things should start working again